# TFS alternative

Tags: unit-testing, tfs

What is alternative to TFS-server with good integration to Visual Studio and uploading test results from Nunit to that system?  I need tracking unit test result, reporting unit track result, but TFS-server is expensive. Maybe exist OpenSource software for this goals?

Comment: Tool recommendation requests are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you have small team, you can consider [Visual Studio Team Service](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/), which is free for 5 users.

You can check the pricing here: https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/pricing/